# Default error display in HTML is not working for formset factory in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am new to Django and I'm trying to create Recipe web app. I am trying to make formset factory which create forms for ingredients. User can dynamically add ingredient by clicking button. I would like to ask you how displaying errors in HTML template works. For ingredient name field in Ingredient form if length of string is less than 3 it display automatic error message. [Display error if length of string is less than 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4gHR.png)

Unfortunately when field is empty the error is displaying in another way: [Display error if string is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gbBI.png)

Could someone tell me why this default display is working when length is less than 3 but is not working when string is empty?

There is my code:

Ingredient Form:

```
class IngredientForm(forms.Form):
    ingredient_name = forms.CharField(max_length=64, required=True, min_length=3, label="Nazwa składniku")
    amount = forms.FloatField(initial=0, label="Ilość", required=True)
    unit = forms.ChoiceField(choices=unit_choices, required=True, label="Jednostka")


class IngredientFormSet(BaseFormSet):
     def clean(self):
        """Checks that every ingredient is non-empty"""
        if any(self.errors):
            return

        for form in self.forms:
            data = form.cleaned_data
            if not data:
                raise ValidationError("Form doesn't have any data")
```

Recipe View:

```
class RecipeAddView(View):
    ingredient_formset = formset_factory(IngredientForm, formset=IngredientFormSet)
    recipe_form = RecipeForm()
    template_name = "add_recipe.html"

    def get(self, request):
        context = {"ingredient_formset": self.ingredient_formset(), "recipe_formset": self.recipe_form}
        return render(request, "add_recipe.html", context)

    def post(self, request):
        recipe_form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
        ingredient_form = self.ingredient_formset(request.POST)
        if recipe_form.is_valid() and all_valid(ingredient_form):
            pass
        else:
            messages.error(request, ingredient_form.errors)
        context = {"ingredient_formset": self.ingredient_formset(request.POST), "recipe_formset": RecipeForm(request.POST)}
        return render(request, "add_recipe.html", context)
```

Recipe HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'LifeBalance/add_recipe.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="navbar_placeholder">
        {% include "navbar.html" %}    
    </div>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">       
        {% csrf_token %}
        
        <div id="recipe_formset">
            {{ recipe_formset }}
        </div>

        <div id="ingredient_formsets">
            <div class="ingredient_formset">
                {{ ingredient_formset }}
            </div>
    
            <div id="empty_form">
                {{ ingredient_formset.empty_form }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="step_formsets">
            <div class="step_formset">
                {{ step_formset }}
            </div>
    
            <div id="step_empty_form">
                {{ step_formset.empty_form }}
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <input type="button" value="Dodaj składnik" onclick="AddNewForm('empty_form', 'ingredient_formset', 'ingredient_formsets')">
        <input type="button" value="Dodaj krok" onclick="AddNewForm('step_empty_form', 'step_formset', 'step_formsets')">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'LifeBalance/scripts/add_form_dynamically.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

I tried to search some info for displaying this error but didn't find anything useful. Is there any way to display info about required field like other errors?